# no native library found for maven plugin project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I want to integrate a leap motion app into Weasis Dicom Viewer.

Projects:

Weasis-maven-plugin -> where my leap implementation is

Weasis-framework -> dicom viewer

Weasis-launcher -> This is where I launch the Dicom viewer.

What I've done already:

- have m2e with eclipse and added the LeapJava.jar to plugin project and set the location of the native library
- installed LeapJava.jar into the .m2/repository folder so that mvn install on my maven plugin build succeeds
- added  into the pom.xml of maven-plugin
- updated maven project

what doesn't work:

- when i launch the application, I get no LeapJava in java.library.path

I've seen some other threads that says I need to manually add -Djava.library.path to the VM arguments. However, when I add that to the launcher run config in eclipse the library not found still exists. Should I be adding this somewhere? Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is my pom.xml for the weasis-plugin:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>weasis-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.weasis</groupId>
    <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../weasis-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>LeapPlugin</groupId>
<artifactId>UBC</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<name>Tool panel sample [${project.artifactId}]</name>
<properties>
    <bundle.symbolicName>${project.artifactId}</bundle.symbolicName>
</properties>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Service-Component>OSGI-INF/*.xml</Service-Component>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.weasis.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>weasis-core-api</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.weasis.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>weasis-core-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.weasis.dicom</groupId>
        <artifactId>weasis-dicom-viewer2d</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.leapmotion.leap</groupId>
        <artifactId>leapMotion</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/sdk/LeapJava.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I add the "systemPath" I can still mvn install properly but when i run the launcher project now I get org.osgi.framework.BundleException: "Unresolved constraint in bundle"

UPDATE 1:

So right now this is what my pom.xml looks like

```
<groupId>com.leapmotion.leap</groupId>
<artifactId>leapMotion</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>

Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no leapMotion-1.0.0 in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1764)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1044)
at weasisTool.SampleTool$1.run(SampleTool.java:98)
```

Comment: Did you run a maven->install?

Comment: Yeah, I update project first, and then mvn install which resulted in build success however, when i launch the program it says library not found.

Comment: What happens when you build from the command line and run that jar? (Building outside eclipse using maven)

Comment: Same result as Eclipse. MVN install on the project gives me build success but when I run the launcher project I get the same error. I did notice that the Maven dependency under weasis-plugin project has my leapMotion-1.0.0.jar but the native path is empty regardless how many times I set the location which is weird...

Comment: It sounds like you're missing a dependency when the jar is built. I would recommend unzipping the jar and looking inside to see what is included and how. There's a pretty good chance it will be something obvious when you open it up. I don't know your full dependencies so I can't say more than that.

Comment: The jar is provided by Leap Motion standard SDK file so I would think that's fine. I did a mvn install-file:install of the LeapJava.jar to the local .m2/repository and that's how it allowed me to compile the plugin project and added the dependency in my pom.xml

Comment: Correct: compiling isn't the same as packaging though, your final jar could be missing a dependency--thus the errors.

Comment: How would I go about packaging the final jar? How do I check the missing dependency? I'm not seeing the errors but if there's any other files that I can attach to show you let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Generally you need to provide an explicit dependency in maven.

Comment: Hmm...how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Seems like it works now! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the actual solution.

But I added:

1. nativedependency-plugin in my pom.xml
2. made sure to do mvn package on the plugin project folder (this generated some files under target/ folder
3. added -Djava.library.path to the VM argument and it compiles and runs!